# simplesamlphp SAML2.0 with 2FA

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I would like to add a 2FA to my simplesamlphp.org installation, which is already running successfully with SAML 2.0. There are some modules, e.g.

- https://github.com/catalyst/simplesamlphp-module-simpletotp/tree/master
- https://linux-bildung.at/2021/08/2-faktorauthentifizierung-mit-privacyidea/

Unfortunately, I cannot read from it whether this is even possible. I can't test it myself at the moment either, so I'm more on the road with theory.

My question, whether someone has already done this and whether something like this even works? Gladly with a source if I should have missed something.